# Understanding the following formula of Throughput?

Tags: digital-communications, noise, snr, signal-power

In massive multiple input multiple output (MIMO) case, I came across the following formula of throughput:

$\tau_{ij} = \bigl[\displaystyle\sum_{j\in \mathcal{U}}x_{ij}\bigr]^{-1}W_i\text{log}(1+\gamma_{ij}) \tag{1}$

where $j$ is the index of user, $\mathcal{U}$ is set of users, $i$ is index of Base station, $W_i$ is bandwidth of base station $i$ and $\gamma_{ij}$ is SINR and $\tau_{ij}$ is the throughput when user $j$ associates with base station $i$.

I had understand the expression (1) completely in the sense that it is coming from shannons theorem, but I am not getting from where the extra term **"inverse of summation of all the users"** in (1) is coming.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.